# When entering data does not update the text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello friends I am writing to pull information from the base TextBox and I want to update the database through the TextBox , but when I enter the new value is the old value does not always save the new value

Code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ID = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
    SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString3);
    baglan.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from pkategori where Id='" + ID + "'", baglan);

    SqlDataReader oku = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (oku.Read())
    {
        baslik.Text = oku["Tanim"].ToString();
        detaylar.Text = oku["Detaylar"].ToString();
    }

    else
    {
        baslik.Text = "Bulunmadı";

    }
}
```

Button Click Event

```
string ust = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString3);
baglanti.Open();
string kayit = "update pkategori set Tanim=@Tanim where Id=@Id";
SqlCommand komut = new SqlCommand(kayit, baglanti);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tanim", baslik.Text);
komut.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", ust);
komut.ExecuteNonQuery();
baglanti.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just wrap your code in `Page_Load` in a `!IsPostBack`-check:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(!IsPostBack)
     {
        string ID = Request.QueryString["Id"].ToString();
        SqlConnection baglan = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString3);
        baglan.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from pkategori where Id='" + ID + "'", baglan);

        SqlDataReader oku = com.ExecuteReader();
        if (oku.Read())
        {
            baslik.Text = oku["Tanim"].ToString();
            detaylar.Text = oku["Detaylar"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            baslik.Text = "Bulunmadı";
        }
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are loading the text from the database and the changed value is overwritten.

Comment: How do I do to me, thank you very much worked since the morning I was looking

Comment: @YunusKaya: you're welcome. Remember to accept it ;)